# R find if value in column exceeds a threshold between two time periods from second df

Tags: r

Hopefully i can explain what i'm trying to do sufficiently. I have df1 with values of the start and end times of activities. However I want to use these times to see if the speed of the boat (df2) exceeds a certain threshold between two fishing activities to decide if they should be separate activities (i.e. the boat has steamed to a new location) or the same activity.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
vessel_pln=c(rep("AU89",5)),
start_time=c("2018-11-02 05:14:26 GMT","2018-11-02 07:48:16 GMT","2018-11-02 09:03:28 GMT","2018-11-02 10:17:25 GMT","2018-11-05 06:39:12 GMT"),
start_lat=c(55.69713617,55.69693433,55.69539050,55.69043650,55.69103567), 
start_lon=c(-5.65051533,-5.65031783,-5.65317850,-5.65859250,-5.65830600),
end_time=c("2018-11-02 06:54:37 GMT","2018-11-02 08:55:24 GMT","2018-11-02 10:00:14 GMT","2018-11-02 11:55:47 GMT","2018-11-05 08:33:35 GMT"),
end_lat=c(55.69462700,55.69539367,55.69454683,55.69370050,55.69302200),
end_lon=c(-5.65454983,-5.65317550,-5.65567667,-5.65628133,-5.65317550),
activity=c(1,2,3,4,5),
new_activity=c(rep("NO",5)))
```

library(chron) 
tt <- times(1:200/288)

```
df2 <- data.frame(
vessel_pln=c(rep("AU89",200)),
GPSTime=c(chron(rep("2/11/18", length = length(tt)), tt)),
Speed=c(runif(200,0,3)))
df2 <- as.POSIXct(df2$GPSTime,format="(%d/%m/%y %H%M%S)",tz="GMT")
df2[108, "Speed"] <- 3.2
```

i'd like to know if the 'Speed' (df2) > 3 between the 'end_time' (df1) of row [i] and the 'start_time' (df1) of row [i+1] . If it does then change the 'new_activity' (df1) column to "YES".

with the above data i should get the following results:

```
df3 <- data.frame(
vessel_pln=c(rep("AU89",5)),
start_time=c("2018-11-02 05:14:26 GMT","2018-11-02 07:48:16 GMT","2018-11-02 09:03:28 GMT","2018-11-02 10:17:25 GMT","2018-11-02 16:39:12 GMT"),
start_lat=c(55.69713617,55.69693433,55.69539050,55.69043650,55.69103567), 
start_lon=c(-5.65051533,-5.65031783,-5.65317850,-5.65859250,-5.65830600),
end_time=c("2018-11-02 06:54:37 GMT","2018-11-02 08:55:24 GMT","2018-11-02 10:00:14 GMT","2018-11-02 11:55:47 GMT","2018-11-02 18:33:35 GMT"),
end_lat=c(55.69462700,55.69539367,55.69454683,55.69370050,55.69302200),
end_lon=c(-5.65454983,-5.65317550,-5.65567667,-5.65628133,-5.65317550),
activity=c(1,2,3,4,5),
new_activity=c("NO","NO","YES","NO","NO")))
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by 'Speed'(df2) > 3 since this value is always < 1. Moreover I don't understand the connection between df2 and df1 since the timestamps of df2 are all from the 2018-11-01 and the timestamps of df1 cover another interval.  
  
Furthermore, I find it unclear what why you use rep("AU89",10) while the other variables only have 5 different values.

Comment: Sorry the data frames were just to give an idea of the data structure, they don't include a clear example of what i'd i'd like to extract. I will edit them and make it more applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's also how you could approach this with `data.table` (and a bit of `magrittr` to improve readability); should be fast even for larger datasets:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

col_names <- names(df1)

df1 <- setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, as.character)] %>%
  .[, `:=` (end_join = as.POSIXct(end_time),
            start_join = shift(as.POSIXct(start_time), type = "lead")), by = vessel_pln] %>%
  .[is.na(start_join), start_join := as.POSIXct(as.character(end_time))]

df2 <- setDT(df2)[, lapply(.SD, as.character)][, `:=` (GPSTime = as.POSIXct(GPSTime))]

final <- df2[df1, on = .(GPSTime <= start_join, GPSTime >= end_join, vessel_pln = vessel_pln)] %>%
  .[, new_activity := as.character(ifelse(any(Speed > 3), "YES", "NO")), by = activity] %>%
  .[!duplicated(activity), ..col_names] %>%
  .[is.na(new_activity), new_activity := "NO"]
```

Note that I have modified your data example a bit, since otherwise it is impossible to find a match between dates (in one `df` you have 11th Feb, in the other 2nd Nov):

```
library(chron) 

df1 <- data.frame(
  vessel_pln=c(rep("AU89",5)),
  start_time=c("2018-11-02 05:14:26 GMT","2018-11-02 07:48:16 GMT","2018-11-02 09:03:28 GMT","2018-11-02 10:17:25 GMT","2018-11-05 06:39:12 GMT"),
  start_lat=c(55.69713617,55.69693433,55.69539050,55.69043650,55.69103567), 
  start_lon=c(-5.65051533,-5.65031783,-5.65317850,-5.65859250,-5.65830600),
  end_time=c("2018-11-02 06:54:37 GMT","2018-11-02 08:55:24 GMT","2018-11-02 10:00:14 GMT","2018-11-02 11:55:47 GMT","2018-11-05 08:33:35 GMT"),
  end_lat=c(55.69462700,55.69539367,55.69454683,55.69370050,55.69302200),
  end_lon=c(-5.65454983,-5.65317550,-5.65567667,-5.65628133,-5.65317550),
  activity=c(1,2,3,4,5),
  new_activity=c(rep("NO",5)))

tt <- times(1:200/288)

df2 <- data.frame(
  vessel_pln=c(rep("AU89",200)),
  GPSTime=c(chron(rep("11/2/18", length = length(tt)), tt)),
  Speed=c(runif(200,0,3)))

df2$GPSTime <- as.POSIXct(df2$GPSTime,format="(%d/%m/%y %H%M%S)",tz="GMT")
df2[108, "Speed"] <- 3.2
```

Now the output is actually with all `NO`, as there is only 1 case with `Speed` > 3, and this doesn't fall between any `end_time` and next `start_time`:

```
   vessel_pln              start_time   start_lat   start_lon                end_time     end_lat     end_lon activity new_activity
1:       AU89 2018-11-02 05:14:26 GMT 55.69713617 -5.65051533 2018-11-02 06:54:37 GMT   55.694627 -5.65454983        1           NO
2:       AU89 2018-11-02 07:48:16 GMT 55.69693433 -5.65031783 2018-11-02 08:55:24 GMT 55.69539367  -5.6531755        2           NO
3:       AU89 2018-11-02 09:03:28 GMT  55.6953905  -5.6531785 2018-11-02 10:00:14 GMT 55.69454683 -5.65567667        3           NO
4:       AU89 2018-11-02 10:17:25 GMT  55.6904365  -5.6585925 2018-11-02 11:55:47 GMT  55.6937005 -5.65628133        4           NO
5:       AU89 2018-11-05 06:39:12 GMT 55.69103567   -5.658306 2018-11-05 08:33:35 GMT   55.693022  -5.6531755        5           NO
```

However, if you'd modify this a bit, and replace in 3rd row of `df1`˛the `end_time` with `09:44:00`, you'd get:

```
   vessel_pln              start_time   start_lat   start_lon                end_time     end_lat     end_lon activity new_activity
1:       AU89 2018-11-02 05:14:26 GMT 55.69713617 -5.65051533 2018-11-02 06:54:37 GMT   55.694627 -5.65454983        1           NO
2:       AU89 2018-11-02 07:48:16 GMT 55.69693433 -5.65031783 2018-11-02 08:55:24 GMT 55.69539367  -5.6531755        2           NO
3:       AU89 2018-11-02 09:03:28 GMT  55.6953905  -5.6531785 2018-11-02 09:44:00 GMT 55.69454683 -5.65567667        3          YES
4:       AU89 2018-11-02 10:17:25 GMT  55.6904365  -5.6585925 2018-11-02 11:55:47 GMT  55.6937005 -5.65628133        4           NO
5:       AU89 2018-11-05 06:39:12 GMT 55.69103567   -5.658306 2018-11-05 08:33:35 GMT   55.693022  -5.6531755        5           NO
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in order to compar `df1$start_time` and `df2$GPSTime`, you need the same type for these two.

```
df1$start_time <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df1$start_time),format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
df1$end_time <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df1$end_time),format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")

df2$GPSTime <- as.POSIXct(as.character(df2$GPSTime), format="(%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S)", tz= 'GMT')
```

Then, you can merge `df1` and `df2` and compar the different time. Then filter in order to keep the good times.

```
temp <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by = 'vessel_pln') %>% 
  mutate(BETWEEN = (GPSTime >= start_time & GPSTime < end_time)) %>% 
  filter(BETWEEN == TRUE)
  #filter(Speed > 3)
```

You can check if it worked, and finally filter to only keep Speed > 3 (I don't do it because I have no Speed > 3 in my example dataset).

```
temp %>% 
  filter(activity == 1) %>% 
  select(start_time, end_time, GPSTime, Speed) %>% 
  head()

#            start_time            end_time             GPSTime     Speed
# 1 2018-11-02 05:14:26 2018-11-02 06:54:37 2018-11-02 05:15:00 0.8461418
# 2 2018-11-02 05:14:26 2018-11-02 06:54:37 2018-11-02 05:20:00 0.8610450
# 3 2018-11-02 05:14:26 2018-11-02 06:54:37 2018-11-02 05:25:00 2.8171262
# 4 2018-11-02 05:14:26 2018-11-02 06:54:37 2018-11-02 05:30:00 1.8165029
# 5 2018-11-02 05:14:26 2018-11-02 06:54:37 2018-11-02 05:35:00 2.0697528
# 6 2018-11-02 05:14:26 2018-11-02 06:54:37 2018-11-02 05:40:00 0.5855299
```